# I am using generic handler to upload a image from database,The image will display only when user login ,but i need to display it on login page also,

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using generic handler to upload a image from database. The image will  display only when user login ,but I need to display it on login page also. Image is not displaying in login page, handler source is called in master page

This is the generic handler code

```
namespace EAAP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ImageHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        string connectionString =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DSN"];

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ImagesContext)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_GetImage"))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        connection.Open();
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            ImagesContext.Response.ContentType = "Content";
                            ImagesContext.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["Content"]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is called in master page

```
         <img id="imgLogo" runat="server" src="ImageHandler.ashx"  />
```

Comment: First thing you make sure that the your handler is invoking or not. If not then check your login page is inherited to master page? then let me know.

Comment: handler invoking only when user login,master page is inherited by login page..

Comment: So login page is not in master page ?

Comment: ok so its means that some sort of code is blocking to call the handler in logout state. please make sure that is there any check you have placed that prevent to call the handler.

Comment: no i have not plced any check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `web.config` file:

```
<location path="ImageHandler.ashx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I suspect it is not working because you are not logged in yet.